# how can show all the countries using tag-input in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

[Reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZT684.png)

Hi I want to show the list of all countries using tag-input but it is showing only 10 entries.

```
<tags-input ng-model="countries"
  name="countries"
  placeholder="Add a country"
  replace-spaces-with-dashes="false"
  add-from-autocomplete-only="true">
  <auto-complete source="loadCountry($query, 'country')"
  min-length="0"
  load-on-focus="true"
  load-on-empty="true"></auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```

Comment: Where does the code for `<tags-input>` come from?

Comment: <script src="http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/js/ng-tags-input.min.js">

Comment: By default its display 10 items,not load more.

Comment: Thanks @AnkitaDobariya but is there any way to show all the result?

Comment: No, I also want to display all results but not found it, if you got it then please post it.

Comment: Hi @AnkitaDobariya I have implemented max-results-to-show.

Comment: okay, thank you. I will try.